# Search for the smallest element in a list after some value

Tags: java, search, list, sorting

Consider a list of integers `<1,5,10>` (assume sorted in ascending fashion).

Given an integer, say, `key = 6`, is there a utility method that returns the smallest element after `key` (in this case it would be 10)?

NB: Looping through the elements in the list and comparing it with `key` is an obvious way to do it, but I'm just wondering if there exist a utility method to do the same thing :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Binary search works, but if in fact you have a sorted set of values, then instead of a `List`, a [`SortedSet`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) (or even better a [`NavigableSet`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html)), is the most natural data structure of choice.

Here's an example usage:

```
    NavigableSet<Integer> nums = new TreeSet<Integer>(
        Arrays.asList(9,1,5,7,3)
    );

    System.out.println(nums); // "[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]"

    System.out.println(nums.first()); // "1"
    System.out.println(nums.last());  // "9"

    System.out.println(nums.higher(3)); // "5"
    System.out.println(nums.lower(8));  // "7"

    System.out.println(nums.subSet(2,8)); // "[3, 5, 7]"
    System.out.println(nums.subSet(1, true, 5, true));  // "[1, 3, 5]"
```

There's also [`NavigableMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html) counterpart that can be even more useful in some scenarios.

Answer (score 6):

Have you considered [Binary Search](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/algorithms/searching/binarysearch.html)? [Collections](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) has a binarySearch method which you could use.

From the Collections binarySearch documentation:

> Returns:
>
> index of the search key, if
>   it is contained in the list;
>   otherwise, (-(insertion point) - 1).
>   The insertion point is defined as the
>   point at which the key would be
>   inserted into the list: the index of
>   the first element greater than the
>   key, or list.size(), if all elements
>   in the list are less than the
>   specified key. Note that this
>   guarantees that the return value will
>   be >= 0 if and only if the key is
>   found.

I will let you figure out how you can use the return value of Collections.binarySearch to get the answer you need.

Comment: Binary search only searches for the exact value in the list, no? In the example I posted above, the binary search will return a 'not found' value since 6 is not in the list.

Comment: @ryan: No, binary search can also tell you exactly where in the list it has to go, if it is not there. Check out the documentation of binarySearch i edited into the answer.

Comment: Note also that if there are ties, the method makes no guarantee which index is returned. If for your specific use case there are no ties, i.e. the list contains elements in sorted order and there are no duplicates, then perhaps you should consider a `SortedSet` (see my answer).

Comment: @polygenelubricants: He said ascending which presumably implies distinct, but I suppose that is open to interpetation. In any case, good point!